# Updating HeaderText of columns of DataGridView makes GUI non-responsive

Tags: vb.net, performance, user-interface, datagridview

I have a Windows Form Application written in VB.NET.
Among many other components on the GUI there is a DataGridView.
There are 9 columns on the DataGridView.
I update the HeaderText of each column of the DataGridView at a specific event.

Event handler looks something like this

```
Public Sub OnTestStarted(ByRef objNotification As INotifyObject)
 If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.BeginInvoke(New onTestStartedDelegate(AddressOf OnTestStarted), New Object() {objNotification})
    Return
 End If
 'Some code goes in here
 DataGridView1.Columns.Item(iCellIndexToChange).HeaderText = "Dut" + dutNum.ToString
 'Some code goes in here
End Sub
```

The subroutine OnTestStarted is called almost after every 25ms from 4 different threads.
The GUI runs on a different thread from the calling thread.

With this code the GUI is not responsive at all. I cannot see any component of the GUI getting updated.

Now, if I comment out the statement

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Item(iCellIndexToChange).HeaderText = "Dut" + dutNum.ToString
```

the GUI is responsive and the other components on the GUI are visibly getting refreshed.

What could be the problem and solution?

Comment: You're updating a grid column 160 times a second?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, 40 times. My bad..

Comment: Sure, that doesn't seem like something that would monopolise the UI thread at all. That was sarcasm by the way. It absolutely does seem like something that would monopolise the UI thread. What use could that be anyway? How is the user going to see that?

Comment: Each of columns (except the first one) corresponds to a device-under-test (DUT). There are about 0.5 million DUTs. I display the status of 8 DUTs at a time. I have to change the HeaderText to notify that a new DUT is being tested. Updating the cell values (that are of type System.Bitmap) doesn't slow down the GUI as much as changing the HeaderText.

Comment: Even 40 times seems a lot. I don't see how anyone could actually take in more than a few changes per second.

Comment: The DUTs get tested quickly enough. Hence, 40.

Comment: The point jmc is making is there's just no point showing a user 8 numbers that change 40 times a second; theyre never going to be able to count/see every one. That's like claiming you can hit start on a stopwatch and see every other number in the "1/100th of a second" indicator. In reality the ones just merge into an 8 as they flicker on and off, the tens are just about visible, but to what purpose? Seeing the numbers rise merely conveys "the watch is running". An animgif will do that.  Just update the column headers once a second, maybe twice

Comment: Thanks guys. I set the AutoSizeColumnsMode to None. Now the changes to the GUI are visible more often than earlier.